# Flows Decision Outcomes

Tags: visual-workflow

I am creating a flow to replace some old workflow rules. My Question is when creating a Flow and using a Decision - will the decision execute each outcome that evaluates to True or just the first one?

Example

Account

Decision

Outcome 1

If Account Name is not null then do this

Outcome 2

If Address is not null then do this

If it evaluates the first one, could you make it evaluate the others by repointing it to the decision like the below?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just the first decision that matches will be executed. What you should do is start with a record variable, then use two decision variables and two assignment elements to set all the values, then do the update at the end. The flow should look like this:

[image: Multiple Decisions]

This is just a mockup, but the idea is that you would have two variables. A Record Variable to hold updates to make to a record, and a Boolean Variable to see if we need to perform an update. The Assignment elements will assign true to the Boolean Variable indicating a need to update, and also assign the values to set in the Record Variable. Decision 3 will update the record only if the Boolean Value is set.

This basically mimics the behavior of a Process Builder, and in fact, is probably very close to how a Process Builder works internally.

Comment: ok that does make sense. I am trying to transfer like 10 Workflow rules that update fields on an object based on certain conditions. Based on your answer should this be done in one flow or multiple flows?

Comment: @CodeMonger one flow is preferable, so you can combine DML operations.